# How can I find text containing url using regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to create a method that will return true, if the passed in text parameter contains a url. Here is what I have so far:

```
private bool TextContainsUrl(string text)
{
  Regex rgx = new Regex(@"((http|ftp|https|www)://)?([\w+?\.\w+])+([a-zA-Z0-9\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)_\-\=\+\\\/\?\.\:\;\'\,]*)?");
  bool match = rgx.IsMatch(text);

  return match;
}
```

I might call it like:

```
TextContainsUrl("here is a text with url http://something.net bla bla.");
```

or

```
TextContainsUrl("here is a text with no url bla bla.");
```

Problem is, that both calls above return true.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: There is no URI scheme that begins with `www://`. See here for all currently registered URI schemes: https://www.iana.org/assignments/uri-schemes/uri-schemes.xhtml#uri-schemes-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the square brackets around `[\w+?\.\w+]` and you should be good. Characters within square brackets are matched in any order.

Try it here: https://regex101.com/r/X2nUNA/1